# if integral of a continuous function on a closed interval is zero, so is the function itself.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

let $f:[0,1]\to R$ be continuous, s.t $\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$ for $0 \le a \le b \le 1$. Show $f$ is $0$.

this is the exact text of a qualifying exam question.
I do not know if $f$ is bounded, so continuity on a bounded interval does not imply $f$ is Riemann integrable.
I am thinking of fundamental theorem of calculus but honestly I do not know how to manipulate further on. 
I would appreciate any help with this question.

Comment: A continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is not the $0$ function. Then there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$. WLOG, assume $f(x_0)>0$. Then by continuity, there exists $[a,b]\ni x_0$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]$, we have $f(x)>0$. Since $[a,b]$ is a closed interval, it follows that 
$$
m=\min_{x\in[a,b]} f(x)>0.
$$
Therefore, $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\geq m(b-a)>0,$ a contradiction. You may need to prove some of the details, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If $f \neq 0$, then for some $c \in [0,1]$, $f(c) \neq 0$. Suppose that $f(c) > 0$, then there is an open interval about $c$, say $I = (c-\delta, c + \delta)\subseteq [0,1]$ such that: $f(x)  > \frac{f(c)}{2}, \forall x \in I$. Thus: $\displaystyle \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x)dx > \delta f(c) > 0$, contradiction...